# cURL response parts of file - big JSON file - PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to cURL a lot of data from my server to a web portal.
The data is a JSON that consists data of about a 1000 articles.
Apparently the data is to big to get in one go.

I tried to increase all the parameters to increase the time-out limit but it dit not work:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);
```

My PHP code:

```
$oJsonResponse = json_decode(call_API(json_encode($oJsonMessage)));

function call_API($data)
{
    $API_URL = "~some url~";
    $ch = curl_init($API_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data='.$data);

    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    return $return;
}
```

What I'd like to try is send the response of my cURL request in parts.
Is it possible?

---

PS:
I am using datatables to present the data, it would be awesome if I could show the first part and load in the rest when I get it, but I guess PHP is not the language for that?

Comment: First thing in my mind is to break the data on chunks and get small chunks from your server. All is dependent from the server where you get data from. Is this API allows to use pagination or something similar? If not, then this is bad code design

Comment: It will only be possible if the API allows you to specify a limit and an offset.

Comment: Do you get any message?What does http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php return?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fetch the data piece by piece from the remote server. Take a look at the following suggested code.

```
$page = 0;
$resp = true;
while ($resp) {
    $page++;
    $resp = call_API(json_encode($oJsonMessage), $page);
    //consume your data
    if ($resp) {
        $data = json_decode($resp);
    }
}

function call_API($data, $page) {
    $API_URL = "~some url~";
    $ch = curl_init($API_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data=' . $data . '&page=' . $page);

    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    //Test for end of result here before returning a value
    return empty($return) ? false : $return;
}
```

Theoretically, the code on the remote server will look something like this.

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$page = $_POST['page'];
$itemsPerPage = 200;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $itemsPerPage + 1;
$resp = $db->getFunction($data, $offset, $itemsPerPage);
echo $resp ? json_encode($resp) : '';
```